# How to spawn an object using the FlyWeight Pattern

Tags: unity-game-engine, factory, flyweight-pattern

So I've been setting up this test to implement the flyweight pattern. It's where I create an object class and a factory to basically spawn the same kind of object with different properties, in this case, color, size, and shape. So I have a dropdown menu for each property and a button to create the object. I want to use the getobject function in the factory class to create the object, but I can't seem to create it right. I got the shape, but not the color or size. It has something to do with the parameters I set up for the function. I don't want to just do what I'm doing right now to spawn cubes and cylinders. That's just a test. If anyone could come up with a way around this, I appreciate it thank you.

```
public class FlyWeight : MonoBehaviour
{


public Button CreateButton;

List<string> colors = new List<string>() { "Choose Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
List<string> shapes = new List<string>() { "Choose Shape", "Sphere", "Cube", "Cylinder" };
List<string> sizes = new List<string>() { "Choose Size", "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

public Dropdown Shapes;
public Dropdown Colors;
public Dropdown Sizes;

private void Start()
{
    Button button = CreateButton.GetComponent<Button>();

    Shapes.AddOptions(shapes);
    Colors.AddOptions(colors);
    Sizes.AddOptions(sizes);

}

public void TaskOnClick()
{
    if (Shapes.value == 1)
    {
         var sphere= Factory.getObject(GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere), getSize(), getColor());
    }
    else if (Shapes.value == 2)
    {
        var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = getColor();
        cube.transform.localScale = getSize();

    }
    else if (Shapes.value == 3)
    {
        var cylinder = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);
        cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = getColor();
        cylinder.transform.localScale = getSize();

    }
}

public Color getColor()
{
    if (Colors.value == 1) { return Color.red; }
    else if (Colors.value == 2) { return Color.blue; }
    else if (Colors.value == 3) { return Color.green; }
    else return Color.white;
}

public Vector3 getSize()
{
    if (Sizes.value == 1) { return gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); }
    else if (Sizes.value == 2) { return gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2); }
    else { return gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3, 3, 3); }
}




}
```

Object Class

```
public class Object
{
private Color color;
private Vector3 size;
private GameObject shape;
private int x, y;

public Object (GameObject shape, Vector3 size,Color color)
{
    this.color = color;
    this.size = size;
    this.shape = shape;
}
public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
}
```

Factory Class

```
public class Factory
{
private static List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();

public static Object getObject(GameObject shape,Vector3 size, Color color)
{
    Object obj = null;

    if (obj == null)
    {
        obj = new Object(shape, size, color);
        objects.Add(obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
}
```

Comment: Your getSize() method is attempting to return an assignment rather than a Vector3, does this compile?

Comment: yeah. I'm not getting errors.

Comment: Do you mean to return just the vector from that function? Because what you have written does not look like the intended use

Comment: yes, I just want to return the vector

Comment: Then do not include the `gameObject.transform.localScale = `. Also, you do not need the line `Button button = CreateButton.GetComponent<Button>();`. CreateButton will do all the same work

Comment: Would it be like this?  public Vector3 getSize()
    {
        if (Sizes.value == 1) { return  new Vector3(1, 1, 1); }
        else if (Sizes.value == 2) { return  new Vector3(2, 2, 2); }
        else { return  new Vector3(3, 3, 3); }
    }

Comment: Correct. Do a `Console.Log(getColor())` and `Console.Log(getSize())` to ensure you are getting the right things before you create the object and post it as an edit please

Comment: Where would I place that? It wouldn't work in the paremeters, and I'm not trying to use them outside of the factory class.

Comment: Place it at the top of your TaskOnClick() method prior to the if statement just as a debugging step to ensure your Dropdowns are sending the right values and to figure out if it's in another portion of your program

Comment: It comes through, it says '(1.0,1.0,1.0) UnityEngine.Debug::Log(Object)

Comment: Does the size change how you want it yet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176681/discussion-between-user8048595-and-easton-bornemeier).

Comment: No. It works when I do it like I did with the cubes and cylinders, but I want to do it like I'm doing with the spheres.